# Bootstrap4: vertical align button at the bottom

Tags: bootstrap-4, flexbox

I've hard time to align the button at the bottom of each card:
https://jsfiddle.net/xzgsnk85/

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <div class="card h-100">
        <div class="white-bg rounded text-center p-4 mt-2">
            <div class="partner-logo mb-1">
                <img src="coding.svg" alt="partner logo" class="img-fluid">
                <p class="lead mb-3">J'ai un problème avec mon site web</p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="btn primary-solid-btn mt-auto">Sélectionner</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used `mt-auto` but no effect.

What I'm missing here please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use flex to align the button at the bottom. Add `d-flex`, `flex-column`, `justify-content-between` and `h-100` classes to the `<div>`

```
<div class="white-bg rounded text-center p-4 mt-2 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between h-100">
```

Comment: Amazin! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Np. Glad to help.